# Redundant relation: Is this a violation of database normalization?

Tags: database, eloquent, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I have a table with products that I offer. For each product ever sold, an entry is created in the ProductInstance table. This refers to this instance of the product and contains information such as the next due date (if the product is to be billed monthly) and other information relevant to this instance (e.g. personal branding).

For understanding: The products are service contracts. The template of the contract is stored in the product table (e.g. "Monthly lawn mowing"). The product instance is then e.g. "Monthly lawn mowing in sample street" and contains information like the size of the garden or something specific to this instance of the service instead of the general product.

An invoice is created for a product instance either one time or recurring. An Invoice may consists of several entries. Each entry is represented by an element in the InvoiceEntry table. This is linked to the ProductInstance to create the reference to the invoice.

I want to extend the database with purchase orders. To do this, a record is created in the Order table. This contains a relation to the customer and e.g. the order date. The single products of the order are mapped by an OrderEntry. The initial invoice generated for the order is linked via the field "invoice_id" in the table order. The invoice items from the initial order are created per OrderEntry and create one InvoiceEntry each. However, I want the ProductInstance to be created only after the invoice is paid. Therefore the OrderEntry has a relation to the product and not only to the ProductInstance. Once the order has been created, the instance is created and linked to the OrderEntry.

I see the problem that the relation between Order and Invoice is doubled: once Order <-> Invoice and once Order <-> OrderEntry <-> InvoiceEntry <-> Invoice.

And for the Product: OrderEntry <-> Product and OrderEntry <-> ProductInstance <-> Product.

[Model of the described database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET7fN.png)

My question is if this "duplicate" relation is problematic, or could cause problems later. One case that feels messy to me is, what should I do if I want to upgrade the ProductInstance later (to an other product [e.g. upgrade to bigger service])? The order would still show the old product_id but the instance would point to a new product_id.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck/unsure? On what step among which steps following what published presentation of what design method/process given what? It is not clear what you think is a problem or why. And it is not clear what you think this has to do with DB normalization. [ask] [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: @philipxy My specific question is whether it is problematic or against best practice for an OrderEntry to have two Relations to a product. Once directly and once via the ProductInstance table. The reference to the normalization of the database comes from the fact that I see this double relation as redundancy, which I think should be prevented (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_2NF).

Comment: Good to see a real-life example rather than abstract exercise. It's common in ERP schemas for there to be some level of denormalisation. But I don't see in your business requirements the typical scenarios that lead to that: are all `Invoices` driven from `Orders`? Or are there cash sales? Are all `Orders`/`Invoices` for `Product`? Or do you bill for services/repairs?

Comment: And the `ProductInstance` table just looks wrong/it's trying to cover a rag-bag of requirements that should be split out. "product is to be billed monthly" doesn't make sense: deliver repeats of the product monthly; then invoice for what's delivered. Or is this a rental/leasehold? Then you aren't selling the product at all, you're selling the right to use an item, whose ownership remains with the lessor.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. "Normalization" means putting into a 1NF and/or higher NF when helpful by replacing a base table by certain projections of it that natural join back to it. It doesn't mean "reduce redundancy" in some more general sense. So you are not clear. Please act on my earlier comments. Especially, "What is your 1 specific" question. If your method you follow says to do something, why would there be a problem?--Rhetorical. PS [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284)

Comment: BTW I hate to see tables all with a useless identifier; all named `id`. The `id` on `Product` is redundant, because it's doing the same job as `product_master_id`. The `id` on `Invoice` appears on `InvoiceDetail` as `invoice_id` -- why different name?
`Invoice` appears to be lacking `invoice_date` -- that is, transaction/tax point date, which is a different business requirement vs `created`/`updated`. For `Order` how are you capturing date placed, delivery date requested, date delivered? How does that relate to cyclic billing for `ProductInstance`? -- if that's what you're trying to express.

Comment: In the relational model & ERM a table represents a relation(ship)/association--base table or query result. "Relation(ship)" meaning a FK is an ubiquitous abuse of terminology. A SQL FK constraint says values appear elsewhere uniquely. There's no reason some entities can't be related by multiple relation(ship)s/associations or have multiple FKs between them. Follow a competent design method. If you don't say why you see/suspect a problem then you are just asking for a textbook & bespoke tutorial with no details on what you do or don't understand or misunderstand in a method you don't identify.

Comment: Only the 1st @ to a non-poster commenter notifies. [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) "Please clarify via edits, not comments." Comments are for asking for clarifications in posts & indicating problems in posts. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. PS You haven't addressed the issues in my comments. PS Putting words in scare quotes does not clarify the idiosyncratic meaning that you don't make clear by actually saying what you mean. And 'duplicate' doesn't mean anything in particular in the 1st place. And which/what is 'this "duplicate" relation'?

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice example of real-life messy requirements, where the 'pure' theory of normalisation has to be tempered by compromises. There's no 'slam-dunk right' approach; there's some definitely 'wrong' approaches -- your proposed schema exhibits some of those. I suspect there's not even a 'best' approach. Thank you for expanding the description of the business context -- especially for the `ProductInstance` table.

But still your description won't support legally required behaviour:

> An invoice is created for a product instance either one time or recurring. An `Invoice` may consists of several entries. Each entry is represented by an element in the `InvoiceEntry` table.

> ... I want the `ProductInstance` to be created only after the `invoice` is paid.

An invoice represents an indebtedness from customer to supplier. It applies at one date only, not "recurring". (So leaving out the `Invoice` date has exactly got in the way of you "thinking about relations".) A recurring or cyclical billing arrangement would be represented by something like a 'contract' table, from which an `Invoice` is generated by some scheduled process.

Or ... your "recurring" means the invoice is paid once up-front for a recurring *service*(?) Still you need an `Invoice` date. The terms of service/its recurrence would be on the `ProductInstance` table.

I can see no merit in delaying recording the `ProductInstance` 'til after invoice payment. Where are you going to hold the terms of service in the meantime? If you're raising an invoice, your auditors/the statutory authorities will want you to provide records of what the indebtedness relates to. Create `ProductInstance` *ab initio* and put a `status` on it. (Or in the application look up the `Invoice`'s paid status before actually providing the service.)

There's something else about `Invoice`s you're currently failing to capture -- and that has also lead you to a wrong design: in general there is more making up the total $ value of an invoice than product lines, such as discounts applying to the invoice overall rather than particular products; delivery charges; installation costs or inspection/certification; taxes (local/State/Federal).

From your description perhaps the only one applying is taxes. ("in this world nothing can be said to be certain, except death and taxes.") And taxes are not specific to products/no `product_instance_id` is applicable on an `InvoiceEntry`.

For this reason, on ERP schemas in general, there is no foreign key declared from `InvoiceEntry` to `Product/Instance`. (In your case you might get away with `product_instance_id` being nullable, but yeuch.) There might be a system-generated `XRef` text column, which contains different content according to what the `InvoiceEntry` represents, but any referencing can't be declared to the schema. (There might be a 'fully normalised' way to represent that with an auxiliary linkage table, but maintaining that in step adds too much complexity to the application.)

> I see the problem that the relation between `Order` and `Invoice` is doubled: once `Order` <-> `Invoice` and once `Order` <-> `OrderEntry` <-> `InvoiceEntry` <-> `Invoice`.

Again think about the business sequence of operations that generate these records: ordering happens as a prelude to invoicing. You can't put an `invoice_id` on `Order`, because you haven't created the `Invoice` yet. You might put the `order_id`  on `Invoice`. But here you're again in the situation that not all `Invoice`s arrive via `Order`s -- some might be cash sales/immediate delivery. (You could make `order_id` nullable, but yeuch.) For this reason on ERP schemas in general, there is no foreign key declared from `Invoice` to `Order`, etc, etc.

And the same thinking with `OrderEntry` <-> `InvoiceEntry`: your proposed schema has the sequencing wrong/the reference points the wrong way. (And not every `InvoiceEntry` will have corresponding `OrderEntry`.)

On `OrderEntry`, having all of `(OrderEntry)id` and `product_id` and `product_instance_id` seems to me to give you way too many opportunities for tangling it all up. Can an `Order` have multiple `Entry`s for the same `product_id`? -- why/how? Can it have multiple `Entry`s for the same `product_instance_id`? -- why/how? Can there be a `product_instance_id` which refers to a different `product_id` than `OrderEntry.product_id`? This is exactly the sort of risk for confusing entanglement that normalisation aims to remove/reduce.

The customer is ordering a `ProductInstance`: mowing a particular size of garden at a particular address, fortnightly on a Tuesday afternnon. So `OrderEntry.product_instance_id` is what you want; `.product_id` is wrong. So (again) you need to create `ProductInstance` at time of recording the `Order`. Furthermore I strongly suspect you don't need an `id` on `OrderEntry`; instead give it a compound key `(order_entry_id, product_instance_id)`. [**]

[**] I see you're using 'eloquent'. I suspect this is requiring `id` on every table. So you're not even using a relational database, this is some sort of Object-Relational hybrid. Insisting on a dedicated single `id` as key on every table is toxic. It has lead schema designers astray every time I get called in to help -- as here. Please if you can at all avoid it, don't do that.

Comment: 'eloquent' by default gives a Primary Key that is a single-column `biginteger` auto-incrementing. Here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions at '#Primary Keys' says you can override that.